# PHP mail sends everything but pdfs

Tags: php, email, pdf

Looked and tried everything but can't seem to figure this out. I have a form where the user selects certain files they want through checkboxes. This gets passed through and they are supposed to sent all of the files. Everything is working fine except it won't send any file in pdf format. It sends every other format, just not pdfs...

I'm using the code below. It uses an array to hold the file names and I tried using just a single pdf but it still doesn't work. Thought maybe the pdf was too big so I used just a small single page and still nothing. Please help!

```
<?
function mail_attachment($files, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto,        $subject, $message) {
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";


foreach ($files as $filename) { 

    $file = $path.$filename;
                $name = basename($file);
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);

    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
}

$header .= "--".$uid."--";
return mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header);
}
?>
```

UPDATE: Trying swiftmail that was suggested but same thing. New instance of email works fine except when attaching a pdf. So this line works:

```
$message->attach(
Swift_Attachment::fromPath('file.docx')->setFilename('file.docx')
);
```

Yet this line does not:

```
$message->attach(
Swift_Attachment::fromPath('file.pdf')->setFilename('file.pdf')
);
```

Comment: The attachment doesn't go in the headers. They should only declare the MIME headers.

Comment: I would use a mailer class such as php mailer and there's swift mailer

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: Modified a line of code, using your original code below:

Changed:

```
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
```

to:

```
$header .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
```

### NEW CODE:

```
<?
function mail_attachment($files, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto,        $subject, $message) {
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";


foreach ($files as $filename) { 

    $file = $path.$filename;
                $name = basename($file);
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);

    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here

    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";     $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
}

$header .= "--".$uid."--";
return mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header);
}
?>
```

---

---

The attachment doesn't go in the headers. They should only declare the MIME headers

### Here is an example:

```
<?php
$sendto = "email@example.com";
$message = "Message here\r\n Hello, this is a test!!";

$filename = "file.pdf";
$handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
$contents = fread($handle,filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
$encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($contents));

$seperator = md5(uniqid(time()));
$from = '"First Last" <username@domain.com>';
$header = '';
$header .= "From: $from\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type:"." multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$seperator\";\r\n";


$body.= "--$seperator\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\n";
$body.= $message."\r\n\n";

$body.= "--$seperator\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"file.pdf\"\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.pdf\"\r\n\n";
$body.= $encoded."\r\n";
$body.= "--$seperator--\r\n";

mail($sendto,$subject, $body, $header);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks all for your help and direction. Fred I tried your code and received an email with an empty file.pdf...passed the $filename to the body but doesn't seem to work. I'll see if I can get it working.

Comment: @user2684129 You're welcome. Try to run it with an existing `file.pdf` inside the same folder as you run the script. Keep me posted.

Comment: So with a "file.pdf" saved in the same directory nothing happens. BUT if I keep the $filename = "forms.pdf" (with forms.pdf in the directory) the email comes through. Again with an empty file.pdf attachment...very confused lol

Comment: @user2684129 I have a feeling as to what may be happening. Let me look into it.

Comment: @user2684129 I don't know what could be wrong. You changed both file names in the code to read as `file.pdf` and there is content in the PDF that you have? I just re-tested it with a small PDF file that I have and it worked.

Comment: @user2684129 This line `$filename = "file.pdf";` and this `$body.= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"file.pdf\"\r\n";` need to have the same file name (**I.e. file.pdf**), and must reside inside the same folder as the script is run and not as an include.

Comment: @user2684129 I think I know what the problem is now. Your files are selected from a form. I didn't take that into account. Trying to see what I can do to add to your existing code. I will add your code on top of mine, with the modified line.

Comment: That's the end goal but right now I'm trying to at least get a pdf attachment going. If I copy and paste your code and change the $sendto it doesn't work with with a file.pdf in the same directory. Sometimes I receive the email when I change $body.= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"differentnamehere.pdf\"\r\n";

Comment: @user2684129 Did you make sure to change both instances in "my" code so they match as the names? If one is different than the other, it won't work.

Comment: BTW your script does work fine with other types. Just tested a word doc and working fine with that.

Comment: @user2684129 If you're going to test with `$body.= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"differentnamehere.pdf\"\r\n";` you will need to have this `$filename = "differentnamehere.pdf";` at the top line

Comment: @user2684129 So now it's why you can't attach a .PDF that I don't get at all.

Comment: Yea that's what was happening with the original code. Multiple items in the array sent fine except when there was a pdf...thanks so much for your help. I'll keep at it.

Comment: @user2684129 You're welcome. I think it's probably a missing header declaration, I'm sure.

Comment: @user2684129 I found another script that you may be able to play around with. I'll post it as another answer. I gotta get some shuteye. Keep me posted, cheers.

Comment: Haha that'd be great, thanks. If I can't get it soon I may set up swift mailer but I feel like I'm so close!

Comment: @user2684129 I know I added an un-tested code in a new answer, I tested it and it did not work. I found another one and it worked. Re-editing my new answer now. Give me 30 secs ;-)

Comment: @user2684129 The new code has been posted. Let me know... we're almost there! hahaha!! cheers (*Peace*)

Answer (score 0):

#### I also found this script. (tested)

See what you can do with the `$files` array.

```
<?php

// array with filenames to be sent as attachment

$files = array("image.jpg","file.pdf","file3.txt");
// $files = array("LakeRules.pdf","TermsConditions.pdf");
 
// email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
$to = "email@example.com";
$from = "email@example.com";
$cc = ""; 
$subject = "Files";
$message = "$emailBody";
$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "cc: $cc";
 
// boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
 
// headers for attachment 
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
 
// multipart boundary 
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
 
// preparing attachments
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
if(is_file($files[$i])){
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
$fp = @fopen($files[$i],"rb");
$data = @fread($fp,filesize($files[$i]));
@fclose($fp);
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"\n" .
"Content-Description: ".basename($files[$i])."\n" .
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"; size=".filesize($files[$i]).";\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
}
}
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
//}

    
$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
if ($ok) { 
    echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>"; 
} else { 
    echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: So the new code works with everything but pdfs too! As soon as their's a pdf it says mail could not be sent...I thought it had be my pdfs so broke one into many pages (printed as pdf) and finally one worked as files.pdf but as soon as I changed that name to orderform.pdf it stopped working. Am I missing something?! Do pdfs have to be saved a certain way?

Comment: @user2684129 I have no idea as to why "something" is causing that problem. How are you saving the PDF? Try using a PDF that opens up in Acrobat Reader, if that shows up well, then use that file as an attachment. If it still doesn't work, then it could be something being blocked on your end, on the server, in `.htacess` maybe?

Comment: After much work and still no luck I'm thinking this is a server issue since I'm on a shared server...I'm gonna see if I can look at the logs on ipage.

Comment: @user2684129 That's a shame. Well, do keep me posted. I'd be curious to know what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Well, still don't know why my scripts wouldn't work with the pdfs but I finally found a solution. Swiftmailer still gave an issue until I used SMTP and then it worked fine. If anyone has any insight as to why this would be I'd love to know the answer but at least it is working! Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Great news, glad to hear you found a solution.